# Rounding numbers in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have database table which i want to generate a Crystal report for it just to show the numbers as it is e.g i have 11.7 i want it to remain like 11.7 while it round to 12. I don't want this rounding . please help!

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/ns0wu78td/crsytallll.jpg" width="100" height="100">

I want the borderd filed to be double values as i have it in my database, the value 24 to be 23,7 and the value beside it which is 2 to be 1.5. thanks

Comment: You can control the formatting of your number fields (including rounding) by right-clicking on it, selecting "Format Field", going to the "Number" tab and hitting "Customize".

Comment: @BayarShahab have you got a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple, just select the field to which you want to show two decimal places. Right click on the field go to format field-->go to number tab -->click on customize-->then in Decimal select "1.0".

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=9338

Second option in formula , you can give format, so it will take 1 decimal.(check in above link)

Answer (score 3):

If the formula doesn't work then simply do as follow

right click on that filed --> format field --> number --> choose the format you want --> click ok

Check the images for the same
[image]

[image]