# Show Exact Value Using Formula Field in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to show value using formula field in Crystal Reports.
Such as "7209.9462" which datatype is `Decimal(18,4)`.
But now I want show value only with three digit after decimal, like "7209.946" with out rounding it.
So how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding numbers in Crystal report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896138/rounding-numbers-in-crystal-report)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
totext({number_field}, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a duplicate question, there are numerous solutions related to this available here.
The solution is to convert your decimal value to text as mentioned below.

```
ToText(yourDecimalValue, 0);
```