# Crystal Report Round

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, report, rounding

I want to round off the number in crystal report like below,

31.349  to  31.300 range value(0 to 49)

31.350  to  31.400 range value(0 to 99)

how can we implement this on the crystal report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding numbers in Crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896138/rounding-numbers-in-crystal-report)

Answer (score 0):

The Round() function in Crystal can accept negative argument for the number of decimals. So simply use: `Round({yourNumber}, -2)` to round to the nearest 100.

Comment: actually, we don't need to round the left part of the decimal point. The second and third figure of decimals(eg: In 3.349 the figure 49, if this value is in between 0 - 49 then desired value is 3.300.If the second and third value considered together and then this value is between 50 - 99 then desired value is 3.400

Answer (score 0):

stringvar x := totext({YourFieldValue},3,"");

stringvar array y := split(x,".");

if ubound(y) > 1 then

if remainder (val(y[2]),100)>49 then

val(y[1])+((Truncate (val(y[2])/100)+1)*100)/1000

else
val(y[1])+((Truncate (val(y[2])/100))*100)/1000

I get the solution in this way.

Comment: Thought you were using the dot as a European thousand separator.